# Ensure Device.BeginInvokeOnMainThread completes before next code executes in c#

Tags: c#, xamarin

I have the following code enclosed within a method of signature of `private async Task`. My issue is that `ObservableCollection<Goods> goods = new ObservableCollection<Goods>();` gets executed before the below code `Device.BeginInvokeOnMainThread` completes. How can I ensure all the codes are executed and the values are obtained correctly before going to next line, that is, `ObservableCollection<Goods> goods = new ObservableCollection<Goods>();`

Note that I have used await `Task.Run()` before the `Device...` but yields no result.

Please help.

```
Device.BeginInvokeOnMainThread(() =>
            {
                Location loc = new Location();
                GpsData = locService.GetLocation();
                a = GpsData.Latitude;
                b = GpsData.Longitude;

            });



        ObservableCollection<Goods> goods = new ObservableCollection<Goods>();
```

Comment: _1._ why are you trying to get the geolocation on main thread? Its not a UI operation, is provided by the platform / system and you do not need it to run on main thread in your code. _2._ The only line of code you need to `await` is `locService.GetLocation();`, if this ``GetLocation` method is not async, you do not even need to make your code async.

Answer (score 0):

Extract the GPS location retrieval code in a method like this:

```
async Task GetGpsData()
{
    var tcs = new TaskCompletionSource<bool>();

    Device.BeginInvokeOnMainThread(() => {
        try
        {
            Location loc = new Location();
            GpsData = locService.GetLocation();
            a = GpsData.Latitude;
            b = GpsData.Longitude;
            tcs.SetResult(true);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            tcs.SetException(ex);
        }
    });

    return tcs.Task;
}
```

then use it as follows:

```
await GetGpsData();
ObservableCollection<Goods> goods = new ObservableCollection<Goods>();
```

**EDIT**

The `GetGpsData()` is a private method and there should be no problem making it `async`. Yet it basically implies that the caller code also has to be `async`. If this is not possible, do:

```
GetGpsData().Wait();
ObservableCollection<Goods> goods = new ObservableCollection<Goods>();
```

Comment: We cannot `return tcs.Task;`. So I just omitted and testing now

Comment: Please see the EDIT in the answer. You don't have to change method signatures in your existing code. Note that GetGpsData() is a new helper method, which no other code depends upon. Therefore, there should be no problem making GetGpsData() async.